# Robotium test won't start after unit tests are run

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, robotium

I have a following problem with robotium. I have test package with few unittests for my app, this package also includes Robotium tests, the structure is simple as following:

```
\tests
    \data
        \datatests
    \robotium
```

When I start test for only robotium package everything works fine, but when I start All tests in my test app robotium tests are failing as the wont initialize activity at all (not sure but no view is layouted, and I'm sure screen is active all the time), and log I get is only that View robotium was searching is not found.

I have no clue what causes it, so I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen if there are unfinished activities from your tests. In all robotium tests your tearDown() method should call solo.finishOpenedActivities().